# Django - creating model for a tournament

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my model, i don't know how to create model called battle, because i want to choose two users from my database but i don't know how to create it

```
class battle(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(Debatants, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(Debatants, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    judge = models.ForeignKey(Judges, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
```

I'd appreciate any hint

Comment: Your question is unclear - you’ve already written the `model` code, so what’s the issue?

Comment: Btw, `B` in `Battle` should be capital (Follow Python’s naming conventions for classes)

Comment: @NitinNain i know but if i make migrations i get error to add related name and i dont know what name i should use

Answer (score 1):

Try to add unique related name with forign key relationships,

for example

```
user1 = models.ForeignKey(Debatants, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="battles")
```

so the Debatants relate to this model as battles